# Temporary no reading to ground on a Delta system

Tags: electrical

This seems to be a transient problem however if I turn a disconnect switch off on any one of several other systems the problem goes away

Comment: What are you trying to read to ground? Voltage, or? Also, does this happen on all three phases, or just one?

Comment: Is this an isolated system?  This is a complex problem and requires a lot of background info, you can't really get a useful answer if all you give us is a 1-sentence drive-by. I would suggest a) register your account so it's tied to an email address, then b) go to a real computer where it's more comfortable to write, log in and [edit] your question to include more detail.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info before we can help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.